# Leaflet Maps: Animate rectangle to fade out after a 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

In my leaflet map I use the bound function to zoom to a certain area. When the map zooms in, a  rectangle is formed from the co-ordinates.

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/PHDduggs/u1nqwe9s/4/

is there away to make the rectangle fade away  after 3 seconds

Thanks

javascript page

```
        // set urls for maps
    var oceans = new L.TileLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png");




    /// location of map load
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [53.01478, -10.34157],
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [oceans],
        detectRetina: true,
        minZoom:4


    });

    //add map tp the baselayer group
    var baseLayers = {
        "Oceans": oceans,



    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);


// add real map of ireland to the map from marine servers

   // define rectangle geographical bounds
 var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];

// create an orange rectangle
  L.rectangle(bounds, { weight: 1.0, color:  "blue", fill:"True" }).addTo(map);


// zoom the map to the rectangle bounds
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

HTML page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="http://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet.js"></script>  
<div class="dark" runat="server" id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border:1px solid black;" ></div>
```

CSS Page

```
<style>

    #tag {
        width: 100px;
        margin: 3px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility (with jQuery)

Add a class to your rectangle

```
// create an orange rectangle
var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, { weight: 1.0, color:  "blue", fill:"True", className: "auto_hide" });
rect.addTo(map);
```

When map has been zoomed, add a 3sec timeout and fade your rectangle out (note that rectangle will be invisible but still there)

```
// wait for 3sec to hide rectangle smoothly
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".auto_hide").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
       // Animation complete.
  });
}, 3000);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/pc9r2s35/

Comment: cool , fantastic man, I was working on something like this, but you have really helped me out with this, Thank you.